# Selecting data for one hour in a timeseries dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm having trouble selecting data in a dataframe dependent on an hour.

I have a months worth of data which increases in 10min intervals.

I would like to be able to select the data (creating another dataframe) for each hour in a specific day for each hour. However, I am having trouble creating an expression.

This is how I did it to select the day:

```
x=all_data.resample('D').index
for day in range(20):

        c=x.day[day]
        d=x.month[day]
        print data['%(a)s-%(b)s-2009' %{'a':c, 'b':d} ]
```

but if I do it for hour, it will not work.

```
x=data['04-09-2009'].resample('H').index

for hour in range(8):
    daydata=data['4-9-2009 %(a)s'  %{'a':x.hour[hour]}]
```

I get the error:

```
    raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
KeyError: u'no item named 4-9-2009 0'
```

which is true as it is in format dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss

I'm sure this should be easy and something to do with resample. The trouble is I don't want to do anything with the dat, just select the data frame (to correlate it afterwards)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to resample your data unless you want to aggregate into a daily value (e.g., sum, max, median)

If you just want a specific day's worth of data, you can use to the follow example of the `.loc` attribute to get started:

```
import numpy
import pandas
N = 3700
data = numpy.random.normal(size=N)
time = pandas.DatetimeIndex(freq='10T', start='2013-02-15 14:30', periods=N)
ts = pandas.Series(data=data, index=time)
ts.loc['2013-02-16']
```

The great thing about using `.loc` on a time series is that you can be a general or specific as you want with the dates. So for a particular hour, you'd say:

```
ts.loc['2013-02-16 13']  # notice that i didn't put any minutes in there
```

Similarly, you can pull out a whole month with:

```
ts.loc['2013-02']
```

The issue you're having with the string formatting is that you're manually padding the string with a `0`. So if you have a 2-digit hour (i.e. in the afternoon) you end up with a 3-digit representation of the hours (and that's not valid). SO if I wanted to loop through a specific set of hours, I would do:

```
hours = [2, 7, 12, 22]
for hr in hours:
    print(ts.loc['2013-02-16 {0:02d}'.format(hr)])
```

The `02d` format string tell python to construct a string from a `digit` (integer) that is least two characters wide and the pad the string with a `0` of the left side if necessary. Also you probably need to format your date as `YYYY-mm-dd` instead of the other way around.

Comment: ahh thanks alot! that's clarified some confusion I have with the indexing in pandas. One small problem I have is that if you don't put the `0` in as say `daydata=data.loc['4-9-2009 0%(a)s'  %{'a':hour}]` I get an error. Is there a way to force the zero in?